# Access object property name with for loop

Tags: javascript, github, ecmascript-6, github-api

I'm working on Emoji system based on JavaScript & Github Emoji icons , I use a function to trigger typing event, that's my code

```
function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
     var x = y.replace(/plus/g,'<img width="25" src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f44d.png?v7" />');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
```

it's working well , but it's not smart .

I tried using an Array  with for loop to handle the [Github Emoji API](https://api.github.com/emojis)

```
var data = {
  star: "https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/2b50.png?v7"
};

for (var i in data) {
  console.log(data[i]);
}
```

the for loop access the object property but not display it's name , I need the property name for replacement , the final code I expect is :

```
for (vari in data) {
var x = string.replace(/${property_name}/g, data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Instead of logging `data[i]` - just log `i` - `i` is the property name. And you don't have an array, you have an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, a better way might be to avoid the loop and make use of `.replace`s ability to take a callback function:

```
var data = {
  star: "https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/2b50.png?v7"
};

var pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(data).join('|'), 'g');
var x = string.replace(pattern, function(match) { return data[match]; });
```

Comment: it' work like a charms, but since it's emoji I need to pass links to <img> tag something like this return `<img src='${data[match]}' />`

Comment: You can return whatever you want/need from the callback. That doesn't change the principle of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (var key in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var x = string.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), data[key]);
   }
}
```

When you use a `for(var i in data)` loop `i` is the object property not `data[i]`

Also, if you want to construct a regex pattern from a string you'll have to create a `RegExp` object.

Comment: what I don't understand here , why I need the `hasOwnProperty` ?

Comment: that's working , but I can't approve answer yet , there's a problem : I can'r access data[key] inside HTML . Example : https://codepen.io/Pro-Fun/pen/MmaPaN?editors=1010